# Why am I getting axios.get is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been trying to get used to working with packages and npm and decided to start by importing axios to  make a simple http request.

I successfully initialised the project using **npm init**.

The first issue I encountered was when I tried to run **npm install axios**, this returned the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\NodeJS\Another Package Example\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\NodeJS\Another Package Example\node_modules'
```

In order to try and resolve this I used the command provided by the error i.e. **mkdir 'G:\My Drive\NodeJS\Another Package Example\node_modules'**, was this the correct thing to do? This created the node_modules folder and when I tried to run **npm install axios** I didn't get an error, but instead:

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write

added 8 packages, and audited 9 packages in 2s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**Below is the code I wrote for my request.js file:**

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://www.google.com')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

However, when I try to run the code using **node request.js** I get the below response:

```
.get('https://www.google.com')
   ^

TypeError: axios.get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\My Drive\NodeJS\Another Package Example\request.js:4:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Furthermore, if I open my node_modules folder and open any of the files they appear to all be empty, which I'm assuming is causing this issue but I'm not 100% sure.

I have tried, removing the node_modules folder and inputting the command again but that didn't work.

Comment: Could be the spaces in your folder names is a problem for the install to complete `The first issue I encountered was when I tried to run npm install axios`. You have `My Drive` and `Another Package Example`. Try with underscores instead of spaces.

Comment: Might be that installing stuff directly onto Google Drive could be a problem - maybe starting from your local filesystem instead would fix it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I moved the file off of Google Drive and that seems to have done the trick, thanks for your help! Do you have any suggestions for an alternative to Google Drive that I could use so as not to run into a similar issue in the future?

Comment: I'd be suspicious of *any* cloud-based storage to host the guts of the project. Start by putting it only on your local machine. If you want to access it elsewhere too, you can sync the source code with a shared git repo, without actually putting the bulky node_modules into the cloud too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that sounds like a good idea thanks for the advice, and thanks again for helping me sort out my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual filesystem that Google Drive (and other cloud-based services) offer often does not behave all that well with programs that need to be able to access other files up and down the file system tree, especially with scripts. Instead of installing the whole project on the cloud, instead install the project on the local filesystem.

If you also need to be able to work on the project from other machines, host a Git repo somewhere and commit changes to it (including only the source code, not the code in all of the modules). On the other computer, initialize the project by cloning the repository locally and (usually) typing `npm install`, which will then install all the dependencies for the project locally.

This way, all that's in the cloud is your source code, and your package.json that contains the information needed to download the modules - the modules themselves don't need to be stored in the cloud, because they're already available from NPM.